# Nlog writes a blank log file

Tags: nlog

This is whats in my config file target section:

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="fileError" fileName="C:\log\patchError.log" layout="${message}>
```

And this is whats in my rules section:

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="fileError" />
```

And this is how i call it in the class:

```
private Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Error("ERROR");
```

when i run the code it does indeed create a C:\log\patchError.log file, but the file is blank, there is nothing in the file

im out of ideas, i tried everything and yes i have NLog.config set to copy always and the NLog.XSD is present

Here is the full config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog throwExceptions="true" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
        <target xsi:type="File" name="fileError" fileName="C:\log\patchError.log" layout="${message}" />
        <target xsi:type="File" name="fileInfo" fileName="C:\log\patchInfo.log" layout="${message}" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="fileError" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="fileInfo" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it had to do with folder permissions.

I took the built executable and ran it on a VM, and it worked perfectly... so yeah, folder permission on my dev machine

Answer (score 0):

In the future, maybe can help you turning on the internal log.

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log" >
```

Change the value of internalLogLevel to debug, for example.

Hope it helps!